# What is the difference between for loop and for..of loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

### What is the main difference between `for` loops and `for..of` loops in the context of iterating over an array?

Why does this code

```js
for (let n of at.neighbours) {
  DFS(n);
}
```

give different output than this code?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < at.neighbours.length; i++) {
  n = at.neighbours[i]
  DFS(n);
}
```

This is my function btw:

```js
function DFS(at) {
  if (at.visited) return;
  at.visited = true
  
  // for (let i = 0; i < at.neighbours.length; i++) {
  //   n = at.neighbours[i]
  //   DFS(n);
  // }
  
  // This gives desired output
  for (let n of at.neighbours) {
    DFS(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for...of` is more of a `forEach()`, `for` is more like `for...in`

Comment: none, just syntax sugar to make code more readable, when you see `for...of` or `for...in` you know already you will read element by element, probably from the beginning to the end, in a linear order

Comment: Ciao, sorry but when in for(let...) you call DFS function, should be `neighbours[i].at` or I'm wrong? How `neighbours` looks like?

Comment: `for..of` is more general, reduces clutter and mutable state, and allows the target to determine how it should be iterated. The last is very important.

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/for-of-for-in-loops/

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito `at` is a 'Vertex' object, `at.neighbours` is an array of Vertex objects.

Comment: @FunPlanet I'm reading about 'Vertex' object. Never eard before now...

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I am extremely sorry for the confusion, the Vertex object is a class which I have created in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh :):):) ok no problem. Now I know what Vertex object is (the real Vertex object ;)).

Comment: You don't use the `let` or `const` keyword when assigning to `n`. Which means you are assigning to the global variable `n`. `n = at.neighbours[i]` should be `const n = at.neighbours[i]`

Answer (score 4):

**Basic Difference**

`for` statement allows you to iterate over iterable objects while controlling the start and the terminating condition.

`for...of` can also be used to iterate over iterable objects(arrays and array-like objects and user-defined iterables). The operation is executed on the value of each distinct property unless it is terminated by using `break`, `return`, or `throw` keywords.

`forEach` method is available as a prototype method of iterable objects but it is executed for each element unless an error is thrown. (Ideally should be used only if the operation is to be executed on every element)

**In terms of performance,**

`for` statement outperforms all other iteration statements. [Refer to this](https://perf.link/#eyJpZCI6IjBhdXgwY242cnNiIiwidGl0bGUiOiJmb3IsIGZvckVhY2ggYW5kIGZvci4uLm9mIGNvbXBhcmlzb24iLCJiZWZvcmUiOiJjb25zdCBhID0gWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDZdXG5sZXQgcmVzdWx0ID0gMCIsInRlc3RzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiVGVzdCBDYXNlIiwiY29kZSI6InJlc3VsdCA9IDBcbmZvciAobGV0IGkgPSAwOyBpIDwgYS5sZW5ndGg7IGkrKykge1xuICByZXN1bHQgKz0gYVtpXVxufSIsInJ1bnMiOlsyMzc4MDAwLDM4NzEwMDAsNDg0MzAwMCw0MDI4MDAwLDc1MDAwMCwyMDgxMDAwLDcwNzgwMDAsODkwMDAsMTEwMzAwMCwyOTMyMDAwLDExNzIwMDAsMTk1OTAwMCwyNDg3MDAwLDE2MTAwMCwzOTQwMDAwLDI2MjIwMDAsMzYxODAwMCwxOTc3MDAwLDIyNzQwMDAsMjU3NDAwMCwzMTAwMDAwLDg2NzEwMDAsMjUxNTAwMCwzODQ4MDAwLDQ2OTAwMDAsMzYwNzAwMCw0MTEzMDAwLDcxMDAwLDIzNjIwMDAsNjc5MDAwLDcyMzUwMDAsNDAzNDAwMCwxMzgwMDAsNjQwMDAsNDk4MDAwLDM1NjYwMDAsMzI5MDAwLDExNzIwMDAsMTc2MzAwMCw3MDg3MDAwLDU0MTcwMDAsMzE0MDAwLDg2MDAwLDExNjkwMDAsNDU5NDAwMCw3NjQwMDAwLDEwMDU5MDAwLDk3NDgwMDAsMzY0MDAwLDEwNDA2MDAwLDI4NzAwMCwzMzYwMDAsMTE2NDAwMCwyODcwMDAsODc3OTAwMCwzMTYwMDAsODA5MDAwLDE3NDEwMDAsMzQ0MDAwLDY2MzkwMDAsMjE2MDAwLDgwMDAwMCwxMDEzNTAwMCw0NTcwMDAsMTAzMjkwMDAsNzEwMDAsMjAwMDAwLDM0MTAwMCwxNjE5MDAwLDc4OTkwMDAsMTk3MDAwLDEzODAwMCw2ODE4MDAwLDMxNTAwMCwyNDMwMDAsMTA3OTAwMCw0MzAwMDAsMzQ3MjAwMCw1OTcwMDAsOTI1OTAwMCw4NTAwMCwzMjgwMDAsMjQ0MDAwLDMyODAwMCwyNTE5MDAwLDE1MTAwMCwyMzI3MDAwLDI0NzcwMDAsNDI5MDAwLDk5MjYwMDAsNTk3MDAwLDExODYwMDAsNjQ2NTAwMCw3MDkwMDAsMTAyOTUwMDAsNTk3MDAwLDExOTAwMCwxNTkyMDAwLDE1NjAwMCw5MTA2MDAwXSwib3BzIjoyODYyMjkwfSx7Im5hbWUiOiJUZXN0IENhc2UiLCJjb2RlIjoicmVzdWx0ID0gMFxuZm9yIChsZXQgdmFsIG9mIGEpIHtcbiAgcmVzdWx0ICs9IHZhbFxufSIsInJ1bnMiOls3MTAwMCw1OTMwMDAsNjMxMDAwLDU5MzAwMCwzNDAwMCw3ODAwMCw4NjEwMDAsMTAwMCwyOTAwMCwyNTAwMDAsMzMwMDAsMTMxMDAwLDEyMDAwMCwxMDAwLDQ1NzAwMCwxNTYwMDAsMzc4MDAwLDgwMDAwLDE5NjAwMCwxMzMwMDAsMjQ2MDAwLDk0NjAwMCwxNzEwMDAsNDk0MDAwLDY2NDAwMCw1MDkwMDAsNTcwMDAwLDE0OTYwMDAsMTY5MDAwLDUwMDAsOTMwMDAwLDU3NDAwMCwxMDAwLDE0NDAwMDAsODAwMCwzNjkwMDAsNTAwMCw2MjAwMCw3MjAwMCw3NTIwMDAsNjcyMDAwLDEwMDAsMTAwMCwzNzAwMCw0NjAwMDAsOTUzMDAwLDExMzMwMDAsMTIzODAwMCwxMDAwLDE0NTMwMDAsNjAwMCwxMDAwLDcxMDAwLDYwMDAsOTUxMDAwLDQwMDAsMzQwMDAsNzIwMDAsNTAwMCwxMDk1MDAwLDEwMDAsMzQwMDAsMTUwMzAwMCw2MDAwLDEwMDUwMDAsMTAwMCw2MDAwLDUwMDAsOTMwMDAsOTIzMDAwLDEwMDAsMTAwMCw4NjEwMDAsNjAwMCwxMDAwLDM0MDAwLDE0MDAwLDM0MzAwMCwyOTAwMCwxMDQ2MDAwLDE0NzYwMDAsMTAwMCwxMDAwLDEwMDAsMTUxMDAwLDEwMDAsMTg0MDAwLDIwMzAwMCw1MDAwLDEzMTAwMDAsOTAwMCwzNTAwMCw3NDcwMDAsNjMwMDAsOTY2MDAwLDI3MDAwLDEwMDAsOTIwMDAsMTAwMCw4NTEwMDBdLCJvcHMiOjM0NTQxMH0seyJuYW1lIjoiVGVzdCBDYXNlIiwiY29kZSI6InJlc3VsdCA9IDBcbmEuZm9yRWFjaCgodmFsKSA9PiB7XG4gIHJlc3VsdCArPSB2YWxcbn0pIiwicnVucyI6WzQyODAwMCwxMDUyMDAwLDExMTYwMDAsOTMwMDAwLDY3MDAwLDQxODAwMCwxMzE0MDAwLDUwMDAsNjYwMDAsNjMwMDAwLDE3NDAwMCwzODIwMDAsNDkxMDAwLDEwMDAsODQ3MDAwLDYwNzAwMCw3MDkwMDAsMzU0MDAwLDQzMjAwMCw0OTYwMDAsNTEyMDAwLDE4MTIwMDAsNDkwMDAwLDcyMTAwMCwxMDkwMDAwLDc1NjAwMCw5MzUwMDAsMTAwMCw0ODIwMDAsOTYwMDAsMTM0NjAwMCw4NTQwMDAsMTAwMCwxMDAwLDM0MDAwLDcwMTAwMCwyNDAwMCwxODUwMDAsMjU0MDAwLDE0MDgwMDAsMTAxMDAwMCwyMzAwMCwxMDAwLDE0MzAwMCw5MTIwMDAsMTM2NDAwMCwxNzEzMDAwLDIyNjQwMDAsMjQwMDAsMTY2NDAwMCwzMTAwMCwzNDAwMCwxOTUwMDAsMjEwMDAsMTM3MDAwMCw0MTAwMCwxMDEwMDAsMTUwMDAwLDI4MDAwLDIyMjYwMDAsNTAwMCw5MTAwMCwxMDAwLDU5MDAwLDI1MTgwMDAsMTAwMCwyNDAwMCwyNDAwMCwyMjIwMDAsMTYxMTAwMCwxMDAwLDEwMDAsMTQzOTAwMCw0MDAwMCw2MDAwLDc2MDAwLDI0MDAwLDYzNTAwMCw1MTAwMCwyNTQ1MDAwLDEwMDAsMzQwMDAsMTAwMCwzMDAwMCw0MDgwMDAsMTAwMCw0MDgwMDAsNDM2MDAwLDI2MDAwLDE3MTgwMDAsMzYwMDAsMTM4MDAwLDExNzEwMDAsMTQzMDAwLDIyNjIwMDAsMzgwMDAsMTAwMCwyMzUwMDAsNjAwMCwxNjYwMDAwXSwib3BzIjo1MzY2NDB9XSwidXBkYXRlZCI6IjIwMjAtMDgtMTVUMTY6MDQ6NTIuODc5WiJ9)

**In terms of support,**

- `for` statement is supported widely across browsers. [Link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_statements_for)
- `for...of` is still not supported in Internet Explorer. [Link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_statements_for_of)
- `forEach` is also supported widely for arrays. [Link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_foreach)